# Проблема с кириллицей electron.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, electron

Подскажите, пожалуйста в чём проблема и как это можно исправить.
У меня приложение на electron.js, я создал меню с кнопкой.
После нажатия на подраздел "Открыть", открывается диалоговое окно, где я выбираю нужный мне файл. Потом я хочу получить путь к файлу. По итогу мне выводит вот это:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\work\╨в╨╡╤А╨╝╨╕╨╜╨░╨╗ ╨Р╨▓╨╕╨╛╨╜\DATA\2024\╨д╨╡╨▓╤А╨░╨╗╤М\╤Д╨╡╨▓╤А╨░╨╗╤М\1402-140308.xml
```

Действующий код:

```
const template = [
  {
    label: "Файл",
    submenu: [
      {
        label: "Открыть",
        click: async () => {
            const linkArray: any = await dialog.showOpenDialog({});
            const link: any = linkArray.filePaths[0];  
            console.log(link);
        }
      },
    ]
  },
]
const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(template);
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
```

Я пробовал сделать так

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    encoding: "UTF-8",
  },
});
```

И вот так

```
const cp437 = require('cp437');

let encodedText = 'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\work\\╨в╨╡╤А╨╝╨╕╨╜╨░╨╗ ╨Р╨▓╨╕╨╛╨╜\\DATA\\2024\\╨д╨╡╨▓╤А╨░╨╗╤М\\╤Д╨╡╨▓╤А╨░╨╗╤М\\1402-135750.xml';

let decodedText = cp437.decode(encodedText);
```

Есть же какое-то решение этой проблемы, поддержка кириллицы мне необходима! Помогите, пожалуйста!

Comment: может быть вы читаете лог в терминале/командной строке с установленной кодировкой cp1251?

Comment: Попробовал, не сработало(